# How to update stored date every minute?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am working on to-do List android app,I created a function that calculate the time difference between the selected time and date and the current time and date and the function working fine. However, when I receive date from the database it doesn't change by time, I want the returned value that is stored in database get updated every 1 minute, this is my function :

```
private fun getTimeDifference(selectedDate: LocalDateTime): String? {
        val currentDate = LocalDateTime.now()
        val period = Period.between(currentDate.toLocalDate(), selectedDate.toLocalDate())
        val duration = Duration.between(currentDate.toLocalTime(), selectedDate.toLocalTime())
        val days = period.days
        val hours = duration.toHours() % 24
        val minutes = duration.toMinutes() % 60
        val years = period.years
        val months = period.months

        return if (years > 0)
            "$years Y"
        else if (months > 0)
            "$months M"
        else if (days > 0)
            "$days D"
        else if (hours > 0)
            "$hours H"
        else if (minutes > 0)
            "$minutes m"
        else
            return "Time passed"
    }
```

Here is how I send date to the database:

```
binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val taskName = binding.taskNameEditText.text.toString()

            if (taskName.isNotBlank()) {
                val task = if (taskCategory == TaskCategory.MUST_DO) {
                    Task(0,false, taskName, getTimeDifference(selectedDate), taskCategory)
                } else {
                    Task(0,false, taskName, null, taskCategory)
                }
                mTaskViewModel.addTask(task)
                dismiss()
            } else {
                binding.taskNameEditText.error = "Task name cannot be empty"
            }
        }
```

and here how I am using bind function :

```
fun bind(task: Task, viewModel: TaskViewModel) {
            val checkbox = itemView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
            val taskText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.task_text)
            val counter = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.task_counter)

            checkbox.isChecked = task.isChecked
            checkbox.setOnClickListener {
                task.isChecked = !task.isChecked
                viewModel.updateTask(task)
            }
            if (task.isChecked) {
                taskText.paintFlags = taskText.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            } else {
                taskText.paintFlags = taskText.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
            }

            if (task.taskCounter == null) {
                counter.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
```

I tried to update the function returned value every minute, but I couldn't because the function return a value only if I added a new task

Comment: Why do you need to update the stored time every minute? That makes it sound like you're trying to use the database as an *"elapsed time"* store, which is a bad idea - as soon as the app stops running, your stored data becomes invalid, and it's only accurate at the time of writing, not at the time of reading. Generally you'd just store a timestamp, and if you want the elapsed time at any point (e.g. for display) you just read that timestamp and work out the difference between then and now, at the moment you need it